# How to avoid closing Popup

Tags: zk

I have an Popup(not modal window) which shows textbox, when I start typing in the textbox I need to open another popup which show listbox,when I select any item from list box the popup disappears as well the previous popup also disappears how can I avoid closing of the very first popup on close of 2nd popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard "bandpopup" component - in this case you wouldn't even have a second popup to manage. Other thing which comes to my mind is add onClose event listener or event handler - whichever you prefer - and stop event propagation with Event.stop(caughtEvent). It will effectively prevent propagation of OnClose event and your first popup wouldn't be closed.